# What are some good introductory books on type theory?

Tags: soft-question, pl.programming-languages, type-theory

I'm recently studying Haskell and programming languages.  Could someone recommend some books on type theory?

Comment: You might be interested in my [collection of resources on Type Theory](https://github.com/steshaw/plt-study#type-theory)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html) by Benjamin C. Pierce would be a good place to start. It would be a make a good precursor to his [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/). There is also Simon Thompson's [Type Theory and Functional Programming](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/TTFP/) and Girard's [Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/Proofs+Types.html).

Comment: I'd suggest to ready Peirce's *Type and Programming Languages* first before *Software foundations* which is more advanced. For somebody wanting to start slow, something like *Lambda-Calculus and Combinators* by Hindley and Seldin is a gentle introduction.

Comment: Yes, TAPL is *the* book. There's also Pierce's "Advanced Topics in Types and Programming Languages" as a follow-up.

Comment: @MartinBerger, I took a look at the table of contents for _Lambda-Calculus and Combinators_ and it seems a little daunting. Are you sure it's more introductory than TAPL or SF?

Comment: @StevenShaw Hindley/Seldin starts with the very basics and proceeds really slowly, but comprehensively. The type theoretical part doesn't do anything fancy. Maybe Hindley's _Basic Simple Type Theory_ is also appropriate. I've never held it in my hands though.

Answer (score 11):

Barendregts [Lambda Calculi with Types](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/barendregt.pdf) is more advanced, but it covers some important topics in the "classical" theory of types.

Comment: Thanks @cody, I'd neglected to mention Barendregt in my [collection of resources on the subject](http://github.com/steshaw/plt-study).

Answer (score 9):

Robert Harper's book Practical Foundations for Programming Languages (available as a draft online: [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/pfpl/2nded.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/pfpl/2nded.pdf)) is a somewhat more intense alternative to Types and Programming Languages.

Answer (score 5):

It's more about mathematical foundations and less about computer science, but the book [Homotopy Type Theory: Univalent Foundations of Mathematics](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) is available for free in pdf form under a CC license.

Comment: I like the topic and the book, but clearly, it's not like the it doesn't assume you're familiar with the rules of lambda abstractions, reductions etc. already. The OP, coming from using Haskell and now being curious about type theory, will be baffled by the interpretation of homotopy theory via identity types, 80 pages in. :)

Comment: I agree with @NikolajK that the Hott book is too advanced for a type-theory beginner. A good route for a Haskell programmer is to learn [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) first. Agda is (simplifying a bit) Haskell with dependent types, and has been used to formalise Hott.

Comment: Not introductory :)

Answer (score 4):

Another nice book that weaves type theory with programming in a functional language is Didier Remy's [Using, Understanding, and Unraveling the OCaml Language](http://gallium.inria.fr/~remy/cours/appsem/ocaml.pdf).